yt-dlp --download-archive how to add a comment to an item?
I have a daily cron job that checks that checks a specific Youtube channel and downloads videos which are new and haven't been explicitly excluded via --download-archive line item(exclude specific licensed content).
This file is rather long and I wanted to add some comments to each line on what exactly and why is manually excluded.
This is what it looks like
$ cat DOWNLOAD_ARCHIVE_FILE1
youtube urlhandle1
youtube urlhandle2

# Usage is like `yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/somepath  --download-archive DOWNLOAD_ARCHIVE_FILE1`


I tried adding a comment as a third "column" in that archive file(prefixed w/ # and not) and it didn't work - such line is ignored and the file is downloaded regardless.
So, the question is how to add a comment to a line item in yt-dlp download archive?

The following solution seems to work, just add a comment somewhere next to your referenced line, like so:
youtube downloadedearlier1
# added because video is too old
youtube jNQXAC9IVRw
youtube someotherid


An alternative solution might be to create a git repository for that download archive file and store your comments as git commit messages for specific lines
